# Ansible указание на конкретный хост

Tags: linux, ansible, yml

Собственно вопрос: Как в ansible написать playbook при указывании группы хостов, применять определенные действие направленные только на нужный хост.

```
- hosts: serverA
  remote_user: some-user
  become: yes
  gather_facts: False
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  tasks:
   - name: Import image
     raw: docker load -i /tmp/some-image
   - name: Stop and remove old container and start new container
     raw: docker run -d -e env=production -e HOST=someserverD --name somename somerepo/some-image


- hosts: serverB
  remote_user: some-user
  become: yes
  gather_facts: False
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  tasks:
   - name: Import image
     raw: docker load -i /tmp/some-image

   - name: Stop and remove old container and start new container
     raw: docker run -d -e env=production -e HOST=someserverC --name somename somerepo/some-image
```

Может есть какой-нибудь способ писать короче или используя какие-либо переменные чтобы не расписывать оба хоста?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае необходимо использовать [group_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#group-variables) (или host_vars, если речь об индивидуальных хостах).

Сделать переменную `some_host` и задать её значение `someserverD` для одних серверов и `someserverC` – для других.

В таске использовать параметризацию:

```
raw: docker run -d -e env=production -e HOST={{ some_host }} --name somename somerepo/some-image
```

В таком случае можно схлопнуть плейбук в единый плей (play) и для каждого из хостов Ansible будет подставлять нужное значение переменной.